# Mongodb query execution takes long time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

Below is my mongodb 3.0 query, its taking long time (4+ seconds) for execution, the dataset is just 4.3 million documents:

```
db.getCollection('TestingCollection').aggregate([ 
    { $match: { 
        myDate: { $gte: new Date(949384052490) }, 
        $and: [ 
            { 
                myDate: { $lte: new Date(1448257684431) }, 
                $and: [ { myId: 10 } ] 
            }
        ], 
        type: { $ne: "Contractor" } 
    }}, 
    { $project: { 
        retailerName: 1,
        unitSold: 1, 
        year: { $year: [ "$myDate" ] },
        currency: 1, 
        totalSales: { $multiply: [ "$unitSold", "$itemPrice" ] } 
    }}, 
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            retailerName: "$retailerName", 
            year: "$year",      
            currency: "$currency" 
        }, 
        netSales: { $sum: "$revenue" }, 
        netUnitSold: { $sum: "$unitSold" }, 
        totalSales: { $sum:"$totalSales" } 
    }}
] )
```

The compound Indexed fields :

```
(myDate : 1, retailerName:1, type:1, myId:1).
```

The same query with

```
type: { $eq: "Contractor" }
```

takes milliseconds to execute.

Please let know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The "range selection" is specified incorrectly, and your usage of `$and` is not correct. In fact only the "last" argument is being considered, therefore it's just looking for everything *"greater than the date with `myId` equal to `10`"*, which is of course not correct.

Here's the correct query syntax for your `$match`:

```js
{ "$match": { 
    "myDate": { 
        "$gte": new Date(949384052490),
        "$lte": new Date(1448257684431)
    },
    "myId": 10,
    "type": { "$ne": "Contractor" }
}}
```

No need for any `$and` as all MongoDB query arguments already are an **AND** condition anyway.

You should also look at combining the `$project` and `$group` stages, as this usually means they can be combined when they occur one after the other. At least it's more efficient that way.

But of course the bulk of time is being wasted in the initial `$match`, which would have been selecting the incorrect results anyway.

---

Optimal pipeline for `$group` and no `$project`:

```js
{ "$group": { 
    "_id": { 
        "retailerName": "$retailerName", 
        "year": { "$year": "$myDate" },      
        "currency": "$currency"
    }, 
    "netSales": { "$sum": "$revenue" }, 
    "netUnitSold": { "$sum": "$unitSold" }, 
    "totalSales": { "$sum": 
        { "$multiply": [ "$unitSold", "$itemPrice" ] }
    }
}}
```

So the whole pipeline is now just `$match` then `$group`.

---

### Working with spring mongo

If you are working with spring-mongo, then there are current limitations on the combined `$group` by supported operators with compound keys and calculated values in accumulators, but you can work around these. As to the `$and` statements, that is really a matter of syntax, and not spring mongo's fault.

First set up a custom class for the "group" in the aggregation pipeline:

```js
public class CustomGroupOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomGroupOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Then contruct the pipeline using that class:

```js
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(
                Criteria.where("myDate")
                        .gte(new Date(new Long("949384052490")))
                        .lte(new Date(new Long("1448257684431")))
                        .and("myId").is(10)
                        .and("type").ne("Contractor")
        ),
        new CustomGroupOperation(
            new BasicDBObject(
                "$group", new BasicDBObject(
                    "_id", new BasicDBObject(
                        "retailerName", "$retailerName"
                    ).append(
                        "year", new BasicDBObject("$year", "$myDate")
                    ).append(
                        "currency", "$currency"
                    )
                ).append(
                    "netSales", new BasicDBObject("$sum","$revenue")
                ).append(
                    "netUnitSold", new BasicDBObject("$sum","$unitSold")
                ).append(
                    "totalSales", new BasicDBObject(
                        "$multiply", Arrays.asList("$unitSold", "$itemPrice")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Which produces a serialized pipeline like this:

```js
[ 
    { "$match" : { 
        "myDate" : { 
            "$gte" : { "$date" : "2000-02-01T05:47:32.490Z"}, 
            "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-11-23T05:48:04.431Z"}
        }, 
        "myId" : 10, 
        "type" : { "$ne" : "Contractor"}
    }}, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id" : { 
            "retailerName" : "$retailerName", 
            "year" : { "$year" : "$myDate"}, 
            "currency" : "$currency"
        }, 
        "netSales" : { "$sum" : "$revenue"}, 
        "netUnitSold" : { "$sum" : "$unitSold"}, 
        "totalSales" : { "$multiply" : [ "$unitSold" , "$itemPrice"]}
    }}
]
```

Which is exactly the same as the example given above

Comment: Thanks blakes,  Even your query is executing 4+ seconds, there is no improvement in query execution performance.Please help. Kris

Comment: @chiku The main point is that your query selection was totally incorrect, and I've also added details for implementing with spring mongo, which apparently you also have incorrect. As for time, your main factors will be the size of data and indexes. The date range is "fifteen years", and that's quite a lot. You should make sure your index is defined to cut down results as much as possible by the selection.

Comment: Thanks blakes, will do. From my experience using api provided with spring-data-mongodb is better as it reduces lots of plumbing code. Please share your experience. kris

Comment: @chiku My experience is the custom pipeline stage is necessary since it is not possible to contruct with the spring-mongo helpers at this time. Separating `$project` and `$group` causes a huge reduction in performance. But the point of the custom stage is that it intermingles with the helper methods provided. Just as is shown.

Comment: Thanks so much blakes, but ur query is also taking the same time for execution for 4.2M docs. kris

Comment: @chiku As pointed out earlier, such a large selection would point to your architecture being insufficient for your purposes which would then fall out of the basic scope of questions for StackOverflow. The main point of the answer as already stated is to correct the syntax and construction mistakes you were making. The query form as shown is the most optimal you can do and other problems will be related to your infrastructure. Also as already stated, your query selection as shown covers 15 years, and is likely the main issue here and probably also an error on your part. Please read carefully.